# Why am I getting an UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning on a line of code containing a catch statement in the backend of my MERN app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I have a MERN app that is going to be used by instructors of a class to do administrative bookkeeping. In this class, students are divided into teams of 4 and spend the semester on a single project, and I'm trying to create a backend route that when called will assign each team a project.

The model for the Team collection is contained in this file:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const teamSchema = new Schema({
    teamName: { type: String, required: true },
    projectId: { type: String, required: true, default: "Pending"},
    teamMembers: { type: Array, required: true },
    semester: { type: String, required: true }
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

const Team = mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema);

module.exports = Team;
```

The body of the HTTP request the route is expecting looks like:

```
{
    "assignments": [
        {"teamId": "abc", "projectId": "def"},
        {"teamId": "ghi", "projectId": "jkl"}
    ]
}
```

Here's  the route:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
var Team = require("../models/team.model");

router.route('/assignments').post( (req, res) => {
    var assignments = req.body.assignments;
    for (let i = 0; i < assignments.length; i++) {

        Team.findById(assignments[i].teamId)
            .then( (team) => {
                team.projectId = assignments[i].projectId;
                team.save()
                    .then(() => res.json(`Team ${i} assignment updated`))
                    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err)); // This is line 74 in the full file
            })
            .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));

    }
});
```

This works, but I get the following warning on the server side:

```
(node:15264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\pat1\Documents\COMP523\COMP 523 Admin Tools\backend\express\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\pat1\Documents\COMP523\COMP 523 Admin Tools\backend\express\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\pat1\Documents\COMP523\COMP 523 Admin Tools\backend\express\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at C:\Users\pat1\Documents\COMP523\COMP 523 Admin Tools\backend\express\routes\team.js:74:51
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
(node:15264) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15264) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm confused by this because I *do* definitely have catch blocks, what's more confusing is that line 74 of team.js, where the issue seems to be coming from, is a catch block. What's happening here? Why does this work if there's a problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@padaca
Resson: 
The issue is caused by you are trying to send response in a loop.
But node allow to one response for one request. 
and 
**Team.findById(assignments[i].teamId)**

becoz you passing "projectId": "def" or may some other string but the findById always expect _id, so that it cause error and that error catch by catch block and it send the error response first time when the loop executes.
and when second time loop executes it want to do same i.e try to send error response to client by line(res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err)). but as i said earlier node allow to one response for one request.

solution: 
you can achieve same task by:

```
router.route('/assignments').post( (req, res) => {
    try{
       let resultArr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < assignments.length; i++) {
           const team = await 
           Team.findByIdAndUpdate(assignments[i].teamId,{projectId: assignments[i].projectId} );
            resultArr.push(`Team ${i} assignment updated`)
          }
res.json(resultArr)
}catch(err)res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
```